# laravel : get Job id after retriving

Tags: queue, laravel-5, jobs

how may i get access to a [job `id`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#introduction) in laravel 5.2?
regarding to [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-how-the-hell-job-id-from-queue?page=1) i have tried `getJobId()` , but doesn't work.

ofcourse when i get a log using `dd()` thers is an `id` but probably its protected.so i cant access it.

`#job: {#459
      +"id": 233
      +"queue": "offers"
      +"payload": "{"job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","data":....}"
      +"attempts": 50
      +"reserved": 0
      +"reserved_at": null
      +"available_at": 1464615540
      +"created_at": 1464615540
    }`

Comment: seems there is no way except sending a PR to laravel .[link here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13781)

Answer (score 5):

In the L5.3 you can get Job Id this way

inside your job class

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ParseUniversityData implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param $userId
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $jobId = $this->job->getJobId(); // this how you can get job id
    }
}
```

the method where you dispatch your job (in this example I'm using action method in my controller)

```
    public function someExampleAction(Request $request)
    {
        $requestData = $request->all();

        $job = (new someExampleJob(
            $requestData['property'], $user
        ));

        $jobId = dispatch($job); // this is variable job id
    }
```

Comment: Hi i can not get the id in Laravel 5.5 because the job is protected now can you let us know how we can get the id in laravel 5.5 controller  .

Answer (score -1):

```
public function handle()
{
   $jobid=$this->job->getJobId();
}
```

you can get the job id by this method

Comment: when you release a job , a NEW  job record will be created and as release does not return anything it is not possible to get access id this way